# Redirect old domain URLs with subdirectory to new domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently migrate WordPress website, but the old media URLs are being used by external apps and it's kinda a hassle to change the external apps URLs

Old URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/...
```

New URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/...
```

The old website was in wordpress subdirectory and the new one isn't.

I want to redirect every URLS that's `www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content...` to `www.example.com/wp-content...`

So far I used a plugin to redirect each media that I known of but I wonder if there's a way to just do all

Comment: If you need an introduction to how URL rewriting generally works, check [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/1427878).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess redirect from subfolder to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442682/htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wordpress
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it redirects `https://www.example.com/wordpress/` to `https://www.example.com/` and keep path after `/wordpress/`

*Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442973*, I just tested this for OP situation.

Comment: "it redirects `https://www.example.com/wordpress/` to `https://www.example.com/`" - it would only do that if the `.htaccess` file was in the `/wordpress` subdirectory. (And if it is in the `/wordpress` subdirectory then the _condition_ that checks for "wordpress" in the URL is redundant.) The answer you link to is really solving a different problem.

Comment: Can you create a directory named `wordpress` and just put the `.htaccess` file in it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to redirect every URLS that's `www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content...` to `www.example.com/wp-content...`

If you want to keep the old media URLs (for these external apps) then you should internally rewrite the request, not externally "redirect" it. Redirecting will be slow (if the app actually follows the redirect) and potentially doubles the requests to your server.

The following would need to go near the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress code block.

```
# /.htaccess

# Rewrite old media URLs to new location
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(wp-content/.+\.(jpg|webp|gif))$ $1 [L]
```

The `$1` backreference refers to the first captured group in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In other words, the part of the URL-path from `wp-content/` onwards, including the filename. Ideally, you should be specific and match only the file-extensions you are interested in.

---

**Alternatively**, keep the `/wordpress` subdirectory and in the `/wordpress/.htaccess` file use the following instead:

```
# /wordpress/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite old media URLs to new location
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/.+\.(jpg|webp|gif))$ /$1 [L]
```

Note the absence of the `wordpress` subdirectory in the regex and the additional slash prefix on the *substitution* string (to rewrite to the root-directory).

In using the `/wordpress/.htaccess` file it will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.